# how to list users name from firebase with angular / angularfire in front end?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to display the front end of all the name of my users in a list.

I'm creating users like that:

```
 firebase.initializeApp(config);

var app =  angular
.module('app', ['firebase'])
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
function($firebaseAuth) {
return $firebaseAuth();
}
]);



 app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
 function($scope, Auth) {
$scope.createUser = function() {
  $scope.message = "One or more field is not correctly entered !";
  $scope.error = null;


Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password, $scope.name)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
      $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + firebaseUser.uid;
      const uid = firebaseUser.uid;
      const dbref = firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(uid);


      dbref.update({
        email: $scope.email,
        id: uid,
        name: $scope.name
      });
        console.log(dbref.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      $scope.error = error;
    });
};




 $scope.deleteUser = function() {
  $scope.message = null;
  $scope.error = null;

  $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
  $scope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;
});

  // Delete the currently signed-in user
  Auth.$deleteUser().then(function() {
    $scope.message = "User deleted";
  }).catch(function(error) {
    $scope.error = error;
  });
 };
 }
 ]);
```

Where the users are registered in the Auth of Firebase, as well in the Database, -working like a charm!

To call all the name of users in front end I've try the following:

```
  <ul><li ng-repeat='user in users'>{{users.name}}</li></ul>
```

Without any success.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? What is wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use this one you will get the all registered user of the firebase

```
    var myapp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['firebase'])
    myapp.factory('usersList', function($firebaseArray) {
    //Get the firebase reference
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
    //return the array of users
    return $firebaseArray(ref);
  });

  myapp.controller('SampleCtrl', function (usersList, $scope) {
    //Put the users array in the scope.users
    $scope.users = usersList;
  })
```

and for the display user the same code you used and also initialize your firebase application 
I think it may help you

```
      <ul><li ng-repeat='user in users'>{{users.name}}</li></ul>
```